# Conditionally changing the order of keys in Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, json, object, ecmascript-6

I would like to change the order of keys in javascript object based on a boolean condition. The order of keys is used to render the dom elements in an order. Creating a new object with reordered keys would work. However, I am worried that the if/else conditions increase, in case I want to add new orders in the future. Is there a robust/ right way to control the order using ES6 /Vanilla JS?

```
    var condition = false, obj = {};
    if(condition) {
        obj = {
           "a": 1,
           "b": 2,
           "c": 3
        };
    } else {
        obj = {
           "a": 1,
           "c": 3,
           "b": 2
        };
    }
```

Comment: The order of keys in an object isn't guaranteed. You would have to use another data type to store and sort them.

Comment: This seems like an x-y problem. Can you provide a bit more context about your app than the fact that order matters--i.e. a less contrived example? You can use a function to create objects that accepts an ordering array, then pass it an arbitrary array of numbers from 0...n that specify the order, but all of these acrobatics likely indicate a design flaw that there is a better solution to.

Comment: Don't use objects, use a different datastructure. @zfrisch it depends. He tagged and mentions ES6 explicitly, where it is not yet guaranteed for all functions (but mostly is). In ES2020 it is fully guaranteed. For the examples given, in ES2020, it would be possible to freely change the order of the properties. However, it still stands, don't use property order for such things, it's bad practice.

Comment: I understand the `condition` might change in future is the number of keys `obj` going to be same always?

Comment: The number of keys is going to be the same. Can i use maps to order the objects, Do i need a custom sort function?

Comment: `obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, sortedOrder: [ 'a', 'c', 'b' ] }`

Answer (score 0):

### Answer:

You can do this by creating a **Constructor** that incorporates **private methods** for sorting and defines an **iterator**.

This will boil your logic down to:

```
if ( condition ) {
  obj.sort( [ "a", "b", "c" ] );
} else {
  obj.sort( [ "a", "c", "b" ] );
}
```

### Example:

```js
// Constructor
function ObjectSortable( obj ) {
  const private = {
    sort: function( order ) {
      this[ Symbol.iterator ] = function*() {
        order = order.map( prop => this[ prop ] );
        yield* order;
      };
      return this;
    }
  }
  
  let sortable = new Proxy( obj, {
    get: function( target, prop, receiver ) {
      if ( private[ prop ] ) {
        return private[ prop ].bind( sortable );
      }
      return target[ prop ];
    }
  } );
  
  sortable.sort( Object.keys( obj ) );
  return sortable;
}

// Use
var condition = false,
  obj = ObjectSortable( {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  } );
  
if ( condition ) {
  obj.sort( [ "a", "b", "c" ] );
} else {
  obj.sort( [ "a", "c", "b" ] );
}

for(let item of obj) {
   console.log(item);
}
```

---

### Steps:

Here are the steps that we performed to solve the problem:

- Create a **Constructor** that takes your **Object**
- create a **private *methods*** object within the closure

  - create a `sort` method that takes a **sort *order*** and defines a new `Symbol.iterator` on the *context*( our passed in **Object** )
- create a **Proxy** for our passed in **Object**

  - create a *get* handler for the proxy. This will handle when a property lookup on our **Object** is attempted.

    - During a **get** if
      the property name matches a **private** method, *bind* our **Object** as the ***context*** to our **private method** and call it.
  - return our **Proxy**

If this sounds like a lot, don't worry! I'll go over it piece by piece.

---

### In-Depth Explanation of the Constructor:

The Constructor `ObjectSortable` takes an `Object` as it's sole parameter.

```
function ObjectSortable( obj ) {...}
```

It creates an object for **private methods** and creates a `sort` method that takes an `Array` of **keys** as it's single parameter(*order*):

```
  const private = {
   sort: function( order ) {
       ...

    }
  }
```

`Sort` assigns a new **iterator** to the context and uses the *order* `Array` to get the values. It then returns the context.

```
    sort: function( order ) {
      this[ Symbol.iterator ] = function*() {
        order = order.map( prop => this[ prop ] );
        yield* order;
      };
      return this;
    }
```

We create a `Proxy` named *sortable* and provide our `Object` and a **get** handler:

```
  let sortable = new Proxy( obj, {
    get: function( target, prop, receiver ) {
      ...
    }
  });
```

Within the **get** handler we add a conditional that says that *if* the property name we're looking for is a method on our **private** object, we bind the **Object** to that method and call it.

A.e. If we get `Object["a"]` it gives us `Object["a"]`, but if we try to get `Object["sort"]` it gives us `private.sort.bind(Object)`

*Note: this closure is what makes our methods **private**:*

```
  let sortable = new Proxy( obj, {
    get: function( target, prop, receiver ) {
      if ( private[ prop ] ) {
        return private[ prop ].bind( sortable );
      }
      return target[ prop ];
    }
  });
```

Finally we call our `sort` function on our `Proxy` to set our default iterator, since Object prototypes don't have one innately:

```
  sortable.sort( Object.keys( obj ) );
```

And return the Proxy:

```
  return sortable;
```

---

### In-Depth Explanation of Use:

Because we have a **Constructor** that takes an `Object` we can wrap our defined object when it is initialized:

```
  obj = ObjectSortable( {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  });
```

Then we apply our conditional logic using our `sort` function:

```
if ( condition ) {
  obj.sort( [ "a", "b", "c" ] );
} else {
  obj.sort( [ "a", "c", "b" ] );
}
```

Finally we iterate over the items, **which are in the correct order:**

```
for(let item of obj) {
   console.log(item);
}
```

The internals of `Symbol.iterator` allow for us to loop over the results easily using a `for...of` loop, but we can also place them in an Array if necessary by using a spread operator:

```
let orderedArray = [...obj];
```

From the above coercion we can loop over using `Array` methods like `forEach`,`map`, `reduce`, etc.

**Personally, I would recommend building your own iteration method**

---

### How to add `forEach`:

Since we are already utilizing a **Constructor**, defining our own **iterator**, and providing **private methods,** we can *very easily* extend `private` with a `forEach` method.

```
  const private = {
    forEach: function(fn) {
      for (let value of this) {
        fn(value);
      }
    },
    sort: function(order) {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Our `forEach` method takes a `Function` as it's only parameter. The Function is then called on each **value** provided by the **iterator**.

The **great** thing about the above it is that because of our dynamic binding in our **get** handler, we can simply tell the `forEach` method to iterate over the current context.

This will result in **less code** compared to a `for...of` loop or **Array coercion** and is easier to maintain from a functional standpoint.

---

### forEach example:

```js
function ObjectSortable(obj = {}) {
  const private = {
    forEach: function(fn) {
      for (let value of this) {
        fn(value);
      }
    },
    sort: function(order) {
      this[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
        order = order.map(prop => this[prop]);
        yield* order;
      };
      return this;
    }
  }

  let sortable = new Proxy(obj, {
    get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
      if (private[prop]) {
        return private[prop].bind(sortable);
      }
      return target[prop];
    }
  });
  sortable.sort(Object.keys(obj));
  return sortable;
}

let test = ObjectSortable();
test.a = "world";
test.b = "hello";

test.sort(["b","a"]);
test.forEach(console.log)
```

---

### forEach in your Demo:

```js
function ObjectSortable(obj = {}) {
  const private = {
    forEach: function(fn) {
      for (let value of this) {
        fn(value);
      }
    },
    sort: function(order) {
      this[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
        order = order.map(prop => this[prop]);
        yield* order;
      };
      return this;
    }
  }

  let sortable = new Proxy(obj, {
    get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
      if (private[prop]) {
        return private[prop].bind(sortable);
      }
      return target[prop];
    }
  });
  sortable.sort(Object.keys(obj));
  return sortable;
}


var condition = false,
  obj = ObjectSortable( {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  } );
  
if ( condition ) {
  obj.sort( [ "a", "b", "c" ] );
} else {
  obj.sort( [ "a", "c", "b" ] );
}

obj.forEach(console.log);
```

---

### Conclusion:

Hopefully this gave you an idea of some of the internals of JavaScript Objects and how things can fit together using things like a private method pattern. I hope this resolve your issue!

Happy Coding!